# jQuery input number spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code for jQuery spinner up-down number :

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group spinner">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="42">
    <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
      <div class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></div>
      <div class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function ($) {
  $('.spinner .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) + 1);
  });
  $('.spinner .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) - 1);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This Worked But I need to add two option:

- prevent user add number to input
- set Maximum and Minimum for number

How do add this option?!

DEMO [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7jtLa3py/1/)

Comment: if you really want to go without a `type="number"` - input, you could present the number in a `span` or something alike and store the value in a hidden input-field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this all with jQuery which i assume you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Stop people from typing
    $('.spinner input').keydown(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
    var minNumber = 1;
    var maxNumber = 10;
    $('.spinner .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
        if($('.spinner input').val() == maxNumber){
            return false;
        }else{
            $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) + 1);
        }
    });

    $('.spinner .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
        if($('.spinner input').val() == minNumber){
            return false;
        }else{
            $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) - 1);
        }
    });
});
```

I haven't check but should be pretty accurate

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7jtLa3py/3/

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="42">
```

To:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" steps="1" class="form-control" value="5">
```

I didn't quite understand from your question if you wanted the user to be able to change the value or not, in the case that you don't want them to change the value, just add the readonly attribute to the input field, like this

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" steps="1" class="form-control" value="5" readonly>
```

Comment: And you might want to add the `readonly` attribute to the `input` element to prevent user from writing into it like the OP asks.

Comment: your code not Worked: http://jsfiddle.net/7jtLa3py/2/ please check code in action before answer!

Comment: It does if you delete your JS, I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve with it. Either that or phrase your question so that we can understand what you actually want to do

Answer (score 1):

Better Ways :

- [bootstrap spinner](http://geersch.github.io/bootstrap-spinedit/)  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/93V8v/)
- [jQuery Spinner](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#spinner)
- [jQueryUI spinner](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/)

bootstrap snipper worked easy:

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="aSpinEdit" />
```

Javascript

```
$('.aSpinEdit').spinedit({
    minimum: -10,
    maximum: 50,
    step: 1
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have to send that data back to the server, setting the input readonly attribute and adding some limits to the input value its fairly easy.
Here's the demo
http://jsbin.com/yebawihune/7/

Answer (score 1):

With this you can dynamically add as many spinners as you want that are cross browser compatible (even IE).  Of course you have to have included the needed js and css files for jquery.

First you have to create your input.  Keep note of the id as you will use that later.  I always just put the same value for the id and name parameters in the input.

`<input id="elementName" name="elementName">`

Then put this in your head section.

```
    function createSpinner(elemName, elemVal, elemMin, elemMax, elemStep){
        var mySpinner = $( '#' + elemName ).spinner({
            min: elemMin,
            max: elemMax,
            step: elemStep,
            change: function( event, ui ) {
                var typedVal = $( '#' + elemName ).spinner( 'value' );
                if (typedVal < elemMin || typedVal > elemMax) { 
                    alert('Value must be between ' + elemMin + ' and ' + elemMax);
                    $('#' + elemName).spinner('value', elemVal);
                }
            }
        });    
        $('#' + elemName).spinner('value', elemVal);
    };
```

Then you just call the function, passing the needed parameters (the first parameter will be the value of the ID of your input).

```
createSpinner('elementName','0','0','10000','1');
```